# Cannot be resolved to a variable?

Tags: java, variables

I'm trying to write a program that creates random spell effects, but 'length' cannot be resolved to a variable...

```
package Chaos;

import java.util.Random;

public class Effects {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] objects = { "Effect1", "Effect2", "Effect3", "Effect4" };

        int effect = objects.length;

        for (int i = 0; 1 < length; i++) {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * length);
            System.out.print(objects[rand]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also look at `java.util.Random` - and if you want to see each effect once, look at Collections.shuffle.

Answer (score 6):

You declared your variable as `effect`, not `length`:

```
int effect = objects.length;

for (int i = 0; 1 < length; i++) // <-- You are using the wrong variable name here
```

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your code :

```
       int effect = objects.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < effect ; i++) {
```

OR

```
String[] objects = { "Effect1", "Effect2", "Effect3", "Effect4" };

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
```